# How to override UIView initializer in Swift 1.0

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Swift (1.0) inheritance is driving me nuts beyond believe. I can believe have have to ask something that as simple as this but I can't figure it out. I have my custom view which I want to be able create programmatically with init(frame: CGRect) as well as load it from story board in which case init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) should be used for initialization. in both cases I want to call my custom setup method. Like so :

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {

    override convenience init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.myCustomSetup()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.myCustomSetup()
    }

    func myCustomSetup() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

this does not seem to work, from swift documentation I understand there should only be one designated initializer for class which all the convenience initializers call. In UIView case this should be init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder). I however can not create `aDecoder: NSCoder` in `init(frame: CGRect)` neither can I pass nil as its not optional. What should I do ? How can I override them both ?

Comment: `initWithFrame:` is also a designated initializer.

Comment: Yep that works, thank so you. Convenience keyword was suggested by Xcode :-( Ok what I don't understand is. From documentation there should only be one designated initialiser per class. All the other initialises should call that one. How come I can initialise my class(and UIView) with two separate ones. Separate in sense one does not call the other designated one ? What am I getting wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure about that? Doesn't sound right to me. Perhaps, as a guideline, you should strive to have a little designated initializers as possible, but it makes no sense to limit to one. `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:` are as different as can be.

Comment: Thank you very much I appear to have been wrong about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A class must have at least one designated initializer. It may have more than one.

All you have to do to make your code work is remove the keyword `convenience` from `init(frame: CGRect)`.

Comment: Yep that works, thank so you. Convenience keyword was suggested by Xcode :-( Ok what I don't understand is. From documentation there should only be one designated initialiser per class. All the other initialises should call that one. How come I can initialise my class(and UIView) with two separate ones. Separate in sense one does not call the other designated one ? What am I getting wrong ?

Comment: A class must have at least one designated initializer.  It may have more than one.

Comment: Ok that's what I did not realise. Thank you !

Comment: that means `init` does not return self as in `Objective-C`?

Comment: Correct.  In Swift, `init` does not return anything.

Comment: I justed tested in Xcode 6.3 and removing `convenience` removes the error. If it doesn't work for you, post a new question, paste in the exact code that's giving you trouble, and paste in the error message you're getting.